# How to get checkbox value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

Hello friends i have a problem regarding checkbox in codeigniter.I want to send multiple message to different friends by clicking their checkboxes that carries their ids..

THIS IS MY VIEW

```
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="friend_id[]" value=<?php echo $friend->id;?>></td>
                        <td><?php echo $friend->friend_name;?></td>
                    </tr>
```

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER

```
public function message(){

$this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('friend_id','Recipients', 'required');
if($this->form_validation->run()){
     $data = $this->input->post('friend_id');
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($data);
     echo '</pre>';
     }
     else{
     echo validation_errors();
        }
     }
```

When i run it..i get error showing that Recipient is required while i have checked names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you do use an array as a field name, you must use the EXACT array
>   name in the Helper Functions that require the field name, and as your
>   Validation Rule field name.

So try:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('friend_id[]','Recipients', 'required');
```

Otherwise:

```
 public function message(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('friend_id','Recipients', 'callback_arr_required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
             $data = $this->input->post('friend_id');
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($data);
             echo '</pre>';
             }
             else{
             echo validation_errors();
                }
             }

    public function arr_required($arr) {

        if (is_array($arr) && count($arr) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_message('arr_required', 'Please select atleast one friend.');
        return FALSE;

    }
```

Comment: Thnks a lot your answer saved my time...be blessed

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to test

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('friend_id[]', 'Recipients', 'required');
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#using-arrays-as-field-names

Comment: Thnks a lot your answer saved my time...be blessed

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter validation, change the below line:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('friend_id','Recipients', 'required');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('friend_id[]','Recipients', 'required');
```

the issue will get resolved.